# Redundant Modules in Webpack Dllplugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using Webpack 3.0.0 for my application. I am trying to split my references to libraries in to separate files using the DllPlugins in Webpack. Initially I was using CommonsChunkPlugin which allowed me to split my libraries as jquery.js and kendo.js . The kendo.js file did not contain the jquery library. 
After I changed this using DllPlugin, it seems both jquery.js and kendo.js have jquery. 
Below is my configuration

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        jquery: ["jquery"],
        kendo: [
            'kendo.autocomplete.min',
            'kendo.treelist.min',
            'kendo.slider.min',
            'kendo.tooltip.min',
            'kendo.dataviz.chart.min',
            'kendo.dataviz.themes.min',
            'kendo.grid.min',
            'kendo.data.min',
            'kendo.core.min'
        ]
    },

output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets'),
    library: "[name]_lib"
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.DllPlugin({
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/[name]-manifest.json'),
        name: '[name]_lib'
    })
],

};
```

Could someone please help change the configuration to exclude jquery from kendo.js .